# python application measure network traffic

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sockets

## Problem Set

Assuming an application with two networking classes (these are the backend for every outgoing and incoming network connection of the application), I would like to monitor the network load created by the application itself in **Python 2.7**.

Already did multiple searches on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) and the Net but did not get the results or ideas i was looking for.

I would like to achieve the solution **without 3rd-party application dependencies** (such as Wireshark or similar products as I am not in control of end-user OS. Application shall be 100% Cross Platform).

#### networking classes:

- mysql-Driver based on *mysql-connector-python*.
- "general" networking class to check availability of hosts using *socket* library shipped with python

## Question(s)

- Are there python libraries that can achieve this without any 3rd party product beeing installed?
- is the approach so off that another approach should be much easier / more likely possible?